# Docker Forbidden error

Tags: docker, centos7, artifactory

I am trying to use the artifactory v 5.9  as a docker registry for local, remote and virtual repos.
I have created three repos on artifactory and have configured nginx on artifactory server. I have a centos7 machine with docker deamon and client running on it, when I am trying to push or pull the docker images to any of these repos, I am not able to do that, it gives the request forbidden error.
I am not using HTTPS and have used the insecuriesregistry flag while running docker.
It would be great if someone can help me in this scenbario as I am stuck and have no directions in spite of googling out for solutions and trying different ways.

Below is the docker error Snippet:

```
# docker push artifactory.secdev.local:8081/docker-build/hello-world:latest
```

The push refers to repository [artifactory.secdev.local:8081/docker-build/hello-world]

Below is the docker version output:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce-rc4
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    fbedb97
 Built: Thu Mar 15 07:40:24 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.0-ce-rc4
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   fbedb97
  Built:        Thu Mar 15 07:44:03 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: did you perform a docker login before pushing?

Comment: Actually I have given the anonymous user permissions to pull or push the docker images, but yeah even if i try to login, i am not able to do so.

Comment: When you say you configured nginx did you apply port or subdomain method for redirection? Because here with your push command it looks like you are looking for "Repository Path" mapping which is only valid with "Embedded Tomcat" server provider. To test it you can go in HTTP Settings view in Artifactory, then select "Repository Path" as Docker Access Method and then "Embedded Tomcat" for the Server Provider, Save and test your push command again.

Comment: Hi all,  problem was using --insecure registry in Centos 7, I resolved it. by adding it to the specific path location where we cab define the behavior of docker daemon, but now I am getting pull working well but I cannot push on the private repository, it gives me 501 error after attempting to push the image. I am using port method, Please suggest. (I wonder if its related to nginx config)